# Executing multiple .py python scripts in same directory in terminal?

Tags: python, terminal

Is there any way to run multiple .py files that are located in the same directory in terminal?

Example:

Let's say I have three .py files

```
x.py
y.py
z.py
```

I have saved these files in the directory abc

In terminal, I would execute x.py as so

```
python ~/abc/x.py
```

And would have to repeat that to run y.py and z.py

Is there any way to run all three scripts at the same time ? Or some shortcut? Save time than running multiple terminal windows open ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming bash:

```
for i in x y z; do python ~/abc/$i.py & done
```

This loop iterates over the strings "x", "y" and "z". each iteration the variable `$i` is another one of them. So in the first iteration, `$i` is `x`, so `~/abc/$i.py` is `~/abc/x.py`. The second iteration is the same, only with y, and in the third `$i` is `x`.

So `bash` actually do

```
python ~/abc/x.py &
python ~/abc/y.py &
python ~/abc/z.py &
```

Which is what you asked for.

The `&` makes it run in the background. You can do this for any command you invoke.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a programmer at all...
Can you please let me know what the $i is? And how Im supposed to connect that with file names?

Answer (score 1):

I have often used something like (in bash)

```
for file in $( ls *.py )
  do
    python $file
  done
```

I use thos when I have many python-files and want to run all of them.

Comment: I have tried the command in terminal like this:
    for file in *.py
    do
    python $i
    done

but nothing happened...just the python help menu...

Comment: You need to do `for file in ~/abc/*.py ; do python $i ; done`

Comment: For me this worked great after I changed `file` to `i`, so `for i in $(ls *.py)`

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have changed it in the answer now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since others have given you shell solutions, let me propose a pythonic one:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import x
import y
import z

# Assuming you have a main function f in each module

p1 = Process(target=x.f, args = (1,)) # or whatever args
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=y.f, args = (2,))
p2.start()
p3 = Process(target=z.f, args = (3,))
p3.start()
```

This is Python 3.3 code, you might have to do it a little differently in Python 2.7.

For example, if `x.f`, `y.f` and `z.f` are all defined

```
def f(x):
    print(x)
```

then the code above will output:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

probably, but not necessarily, in that order.

Answer (score 0):

bash file

```
ls *.py | xargs -I{} sh -c "echo {}; python {}"
```

you can get all .py file in current directory with command `ls *.py`

and use `xargs -I` to execute from standard input

run all .py in directory in `sh -c`  with command `python {}`
 automatically replace {} with .py files

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.